# Are questions about programming .Net Gadgeteer projects best asked here or on SO?

Tags: discussion, support

I've a question about [the code used with the .Net Gadgeteer extender module](http://pastebin.com/6gzNJD2K) to use pulse-width modulation to control [a servo motor](http://learn.parallax.com/kickstart/900-00005). That's a software question but it is also an electrical engineering question (I think), witness [the large number of Arduino questions here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino) (though [the number is even bigger on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arduino)).

SO has [a tag for .Net Gadgeteer questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-gadgeteer) (with a grand total of 13 questions!) while we don't here, but that may not be significant.

I guess that the general version of my question is "are questions about programming hobbyist electronics platforms best asked here or on Stack Overflow?" but I am specifically interested in .Net Gadgeteer questions.

Comment: The best answer is possibly to ask questions where good answers are most likely, in which case it's probably the [GHI Gadgeteer forum](http://www.ghielectronics.com/community/forum), but it'd be good to ask the questions somewhere in Stack Exchange too.

Comment: Related: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2622/17592